# Two parallel and two sequential requests using Rxjava2

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying  to authorize in two services in parallel, but each of them has two steps:

The first service

1) Log in account if the user exist  (else create account)

2) Create account if the user doesn't

```
 Maybe<String> login()
 Maybe<String> create()
```

The second service has the same steps.

```
 Maybe<Result> login2()
 Maybe<Result> create2()
```

I know that i can use ZIP operator for parallel requests, but i can't understand how to do all this scheme. What is the right way? I am using RxJava2 + Retrofit2.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use something like following for the login/create sequencing:

```
Maybe.concat(login, create).firstElement();
```

(and can then use `zip`, as you mentioned, to parallelize doing this for the 2 services)

The following is a good article that covers both these patterns https://medium.com/devnibbles/rxjava-the-first-3-patterns-4c112a85b689

Comment: John, thank you for answer and article. Now I am trying to use flatmap instead of concat, I can't understand the difference.

Comment: @Delphian with flatMap you will end trying to create an already created account